# Ext lib dialog and file upload controls

Tags: xpages

I have a dialog containing a file upload control. When the form is submitted within the dialog everything is being saved correctly except the file that was selected. I suspect the dialog to be the cause of this.

Is there a property I have to set to enable it or is there some sort of work around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [this](http://www.dominoguru.com/pages/xpage_fileupload_extlib_dialog_tutorial.html) article will answer your question.

In short: the dialog uses a HTTP GET request to send data back to the server and thus can't include attachments. The article describes a workaround which you might be able to use.

Comment: Mark, thanks for the answer. I'm implementing this now. I already know of the excistance of this issue but hoped it would be 'solved' in the latest extlib.