# Null value for fileData:com.ibm.xsp.http.UploadedFile in dialog box?

Tags: xpages

I found a bit of code to import CSV files.  It uses a file upload control to get a handle to the file.  It works great when I just use it on a regular xPage.

But I want to use it within an extensions pages dialog box but it does not work.  The line causing the issue is this line?

```
var fileData:com.ibm.xsp.http.UploadedFile =   facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getParameterMap().get(getClientId('fileUpload1'));
```

It always returns null.  I indeed have a control on my dialog box called fileIpload1.

The difference I am seeing in the client ID is that on the straight xPage, the client id is:  view:_id1:_id19:fileUpload1  and when a dialog box is used the client id is:  view:_id1:_id193:_id194:_id195:dlg_ImportParticipants:_content:form1:_id373:fileUpload1

Any idea what I am doing wrong if anything or a work around?

Comment: PS Just to clarify, I am not closing the dialog box right after getting the file object.  It remains open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for that link Per.  I think maybe a bit complex for me right now.  I came up with my own solution (sort of).  What I do is to place a panel on my main xpage with the file upload control.  My button unhides the panel.  My Import button imports the code but also hides it again.   The issue I still have is that I am still having is updating an "embedded" view on the xpage after the import executes.

BTW I am hiding / unhiding the panel using the CSS display property.

This is not nearly as elegant as in the link that you posted but far more simple.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question can help you: [Ext lib dialog and file upload controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515394/ext-lib-dialog-and-file-upload-controls)

In short: you need to use a workaround.

I use it and therefore have working code available if you need some more help.