# Update view after using file upload

Tags: xpages

I am sure this is related to my question here

[Null value for fileData:com.ibm.xsp.http.UploadedFile in dialog box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204216/null-value-for-filedatacom-ibm-xsp-http-uploadedfile-in-dialog-box)

Which I am still not 100% clear why the file upload control does not work directly in an extension pages dialog box.

But anyway I came up with my own solution using the file update control inside of a hidden panel.   I need to set the button that uses the control to full update.

I have a button does an import of data.  The button gets the file via a file upload control.   This data is displayed in a view on the xpage.
The view is not being updated even though the Import button has Full Update.    I am guessing that the full update actually get executed before the import actually completes?

Is there anyway to update my view after the import completes?

Comment: What is your import doing?  Is it creating documents in the backend or loading the data into a scoped variable?

Comment: When you open the view in your client does it show the newly created document??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by causing the button that uploads the file to display an extension pages dialog box.  This dialog box has an OK button to close the message box but also refreshes the required part of the form.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that a File Upload requires a full refresh of the XPage to push the file up to the temporary folder on the server. At this point, the attachment is just stored in that temporary folder. It's not stored in the NSF. A subsequent function needs to be run to save that to a document.

Is your button doing the upload of the file to the temporary folder, or is it saving a Notes Document / directly accessing the temporary file and processing it via the back-end? If it's just performing the upload, the view won't upload.

The other thing I've come across is View Panels not immediately updating with new documents that have been created. In that scenario, a repeat control bound to NotesView.getDocumentsByKey() did immediately update.