# File Upload in a Xpages Extension Library Dialog Box

Tags: file-upload, dialog, xpages

Is there anyway to get the a File upload/download to work in a extension library dialog box?
The file unload control seems to work but never stores the file in the document. The other controls(inputtext, computed and dates) in the dialog works correctly
Thx

Comment: Don't use a dialog, use an inline form

Comment: See this answer (and ask Chris Toohey to get his content back online): http://stackoverflow.com/a/9516238/785061

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have code to give you YET...  but in the day job we use PLUpload instead of the built in controls.  You can out PLUload inside a standard XPages dialog box.  It gets connected to an XAgent of which this snippet:
http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=custom-xpage-file-upload-handler
is probably what you're looking for.  I'm currently using an SSJS version but will be looking to migrate to the Java one.
I then have code to process the uploads and move them to another database and also resize jpg's and stuff.
A full example will be presented at the MWLug (2014) user group meeting and will also come to NotesIn9 soon.  I just don't have all the code samples ready yet.  But PLUpload with that snippet should be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

What's your Domino server version? If it's lower than 9.0.1 file uploads cannot be done via a partial refresh, so it's not possible. In 9.0.1 you can run file upload with partial refresh, so it might be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.

The following code will work on a 9.0.1 server. Not sure about pre-9.0.1 though: doing a partial refresh with a file upload is a feature that was introduced in 9.0.1. A tip: if you include validations in the dialog, a partial refresh of only the dialog won't work: you need to refresh an element that contains the dialog.

```
<xp:text
    escape="true"
    id="computedField1"
    value="#{javascript:@Now().getTime()}">
</xp:text>

<xp:button
    value="show dialog"
    id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial"
        refreshId="dialog1">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("dialog1").show();}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>

<xe:dialog
    id="dialog1"
    title="Look. I'm a dialog!">

    <xp:panel>
        <xp:this.data>
            <xp:dominoDocument
                var="document1"
                formName="fUpload">
            </xp:dominoDocument>
        </xp:this.data>
        <xe:dialogContent
            id="dialogContent1">

            Pick a file:

            <xp:fileUpload
                id="fileUpload1"
                value="#{document1.files}"></xp:fileUpload>

        </xe:dialogContent>

        <xe:dialogButtonBar
            id="dialogButtonBar1">

            <xp:button
                value="Save"
                id="button2">
                <xp:eventHandler
                    event="onclick"
                    submit="true"
                    refreshMode="partial"
                    refreshId="dialog1"
                    immediate="false"
                    save="true"></xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:button>

        </xe:dialogButtonBar>

    </xp:panel>
</xe:dialog>
```

Comment: For anyone copying this into a new xpage to test, make sure you add the namespace declaration [xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"], otherwise you will get the error 'The prefix "xe" for element "xe:dialog" is not bound'.

Comment: I know it's seems too late now, but this doesn't work in 9.0.1. Currently having issues with inability to do partial refresh with fileUpload control.